# How to search Core Data Child Objects

Tags: search, core-data, hierarchy, predicate

I am having difficulty figuring out if and or how I can search child objects as well as their parents using NSPredicate(or some other method).  For instance, I have a Wine Object that has properties like name, vineyard, region and year.  Then I have a child object like "Event" which has properties like WhoSharedWith, FoodAteWith, EventDate, etc.  I can figure out a Predicate for the Wine Object but what if the person types in "Steak"?  I want to search the "Event" objects UNDER the wine objects to see which Wines are good with Steak.  Can anybody help me out?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Core Data terminology, you have multiple Entities (Event, Wine) connected by a relationship. There is no notion of parent and child Entities (unless you are creating subentities, akin to subclassing, which it appears you are not doing).

All of the Entities are peers. You can start anywhere in your object graph and follow the relationships to get to any related objects. You can use the relationships' keypaths in your predicate. See the [Predicate Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html).